# Customize margin of the document per page?

Tags: margins, two-column, overleaf, marginnote

I want to know how do I customize margin in a latex document per page?

For example :

[image]

1) How do I edit the margin in the right for the second column? For some pages I want to column and for some I dont want it and others I want to I can adjust the second column width (say 30% / 20% etc) -- Thats why I was looking for some per page settings.

2) Also It would be good to know if I could add thin line separating the two columns.

I am novice in latex and I am working on book and I want this format for it. If it helps I am using overleaf platform.

Thanks

Comment: geometry package?

Comment: you can easily change the page layout at a forced (`\clearpage`) page break but it is a lot harder to change it at an automatic page break as the paragraph is broken in to lines based on the starting page before page breaking is considered so the line width of the paragraph can not change at an automatic page break.

Comment: It should be noted that text will not flow across width changes.  Even using flowfram the width will not change until the next paragraph.

Comment: Any samples? I would appreciate that... As I said I am pretty novice at this.